# JavaScript Use of the classes in the forms

Tags: javascript

I have to do a class and I have to do regular tests through the set and I also have to do the tests through a form I did a function that checks my name just for testing and it does not work for me can someone please help me

```js
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;
class Client {
  constructor(full_name, id_person, gender, age) {
    this.setFull_name = full_name;
    this.setId_person = id_person;
    this.setGender = gender;
    this.setAge = age;
  }
  get getFull_name() {
    return this.full_name;
  }
  set setFull_name(full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name.test(/^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/)[0];
  }
  get getId_person() {
    return this.id_person;
  }
  set setId_person(id_person) {
    if (id_person > 0) this.id_person = id_person;
  }
  get getGender() {
    return this.gender;
  }
  set setGender(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }
  get getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }
  set setAge(age) {
    if (age >= 18) this.age = age;
  }
  toString() {
    return (
      "<font size='5'> The full name is: [" +
      this.full_name +
      '] and the ID is: [' +
      this.id_person +
      '] and the gender is: [' +
      this.gender +
      '] and the age is [' +
      this.age +
      ']'
    );
  }
}

function check(form) {
  var checkName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
  //alert(fullName.value); //Check if the variable has received the value
  if (!checkName.test(form.fullName.value)) {
    alert('the full name is not good'); //need fix Does not work
  } else {
    alert('the name is good');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<form id="form" name="form" onsubmit="return check(form) && false;">
  <h2>Client</h2>
  <label>full name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="fullName"
    id="fullName"
    placeholder="full name"
  /><br />

  <label>ID</label>
  <input type="text" name="id_person" id="id_person" placeholder="ID" /><br />

  <label>gender</label>
  <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="gender" /><br />

  <label>age</label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="age" /><br />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="sumbit" />
</form>
```

I would be very happy if I get help it will help me a lot

Comment: Your description of the problem is not clear at all. And you need to post a [mcve] here, not at an external site.

Comment: 1) you're never instantiating a `client` anywhere 2) `checkName.test(…)` should be called with a regex, not with a string 3) your class definition mixes up property getters/setters with setter/getter methods 4) `full_name.test(/^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/)` returns a boolean, which you cannot array-index